# Difference between zero apples and zero oranges.

Tags: soft-question, education, philosophy

There are two plates, one with an apple and another with orange. Yes, they are different now, but what if I take both the fruits out?

Comment: You can think the first plate as containing one apple and zero oranges and the other way around for the second. They both end up having zero fruits

Comment: Then you only have two plates !

Comment: Depends on what formalism you're working in. If you're in some kind of type theory, you probably have a plate with zero apples and a plate with zero oranges; if you're in some untyped setting like set theory, you have two identical empty plates.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I think you could basically make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what formalism you're working in.

If you're in some kind of type theory, where plates have types, then you've probably got left a plate with zero apples and a plate with zero oranges. These plates are not comparable to each other, because they have different types; and you can't put an orange onto the empty apples plate (just as you can't put an orange onto a plate with three apples), because the apples plate can only hold apples. But you might be able to turn the apples plate into a *fruit* plate, and then put an orange onto it.

If you're in some untyped setting like set theory, you have two identical and indistinguishable empty plates. You could add an apple and an orange to each plate without any problems.